# How to get records from database and show in html format?

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to retrieve records from the database table and get the id,title from chapters table and I want to show the chapter names in select tag.

And when user will select any one chapter I want to get the id of chapter and post it through form.

I tried to add the select query but I am not getting how can I show this in select tag and get the id of chapter on selection.

```
     <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(1); 
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host;dbname','', '');

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM chapters");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <body>


    <form action="fileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p> Select image to upload:</p>
    <input name = "file" type="file" id="fileToUpload"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value = "Upload Image">

    </form>

        </body>

    </head>

</html>
```

Can anyone help with this please? thank you..

EDIT :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <body>
    <?php
         <select>

          foreach ($stmt as $row)
        {
            <option value=$row['chapterName']>$row['chapterName']</option>
        }

            </select>
    ?>
```

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#foreach

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#query

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetch

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchall

Comment: Those will help u get started

Comment: can you please check edited question? I tried to get the values from stmt and show in select tag but it has errors getting error 500. @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: this is an error : `<option value`

Comment: sorry did not get u. @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: @Sid that `<option value...` is not valid php

Comment: how can I mix html and php code? can you please help? @CalvT

Comment: You need to `echo` the html. Something like this: `echo "<option value='".$row['chapterName'].">".$row['chapterName']."</option>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your `html` Markup up is invalid you can't close `head` tag after `body`
this is how an html markup looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is a title </title>
    META TAGs
  </head>
<body
 BODY CONTENT
</body>
</html>
```

Now this is how your code should look :

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(1);
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=db', 'airman', 'pass');
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
        <form action="fileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p> Select image to upload:</p>
            <input name = "file" type="file" id="fileToUpload"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value = "Upload Image">
            <select name="chapters">
                <?php
                    $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM chapters")->fetchAll(FETCH_ASSOC);
                    foreach($stmt as $row):?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['chapterid'];?>"><?php echo $row['chapterName'];?></option>
                <?php
                    endforeach;?>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The reason your getting the 500 error here :

```
  foreach ($stmt as $row)
        {
            <option value=$row['chapterName']>$row['chapterName']</option>
        }
```

its because you are mixing php and html wrong. its either you echo the html tags using `echo`

**Or :**

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(1);
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=db', 'airman', 'pass');
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
        <form action="fileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p> Select image to upload:</p>
            <input name = "file" type="file" id="fileToUpload"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value = "Upload Image">
            <select name="chapters">
                <?php
                    $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM chapters");
                    while($row = $stmt->fetchall(FETCH_ASSOC)):?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['chapterid'];?>"><?php echo $row['chapterName'];?></option>
                <?php
                    endwhile;?>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**OR**

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(1);
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=db', 'airman', 'pass');
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
        <form action="fileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p> Select image to upload:</p>
            <input name = "file" type="file" id="fileToUpload"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value = "Upload Image">
            <select name="chapters">
                <?php
                    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM chapters");
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    if(count($results > 0)){
                        foreach($results as $row):?>
                         <option value="<?php echo $row['chapterid'];?>"><?php echo $row['chapterName'];?></option>
                    <?php
                        endforeach;
                    }else{?>

                        <option value="0">No data found</option>
                    <?php}?>


            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not getting any value in select tag

Comment: do u have chapter `chapterid` on your database table?

Comment: yes I checked it and added the name same as database column names, still the select tag is blank.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138529/discussion-between-masivuye-cokile-and-sid).